# how to make an object move automatically Within a specified path

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a beginner with Unity 5.6 and game development in general.

I have a train and its rails in my scene. I need the train to start moving automatically on the rails (within a specified path) when the game starts. When it reaches the end of the path it should return to the start and keeps moving. I also want to control its speed. I've tried many things and searching for answers to make this and haven't succeeded yet.

How can I do this please? What kind of code do I have to write? Do I need to attach it to the train object?

Comment: Hey! You should show your current code and preferably explain a little bit more about what you're trying to achieve because right now the question might come off as a little too broad.

Comment: I cleaned up your question a bit, but you really need to supply some more details, such as what you've already tried.  See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thanks guys .. in the fact i don't know how to move anything in unity .. I searched a lot and did not find a solution .. i need to move the train in specific path .. please help